# Error getting photos from a Facebook album using FQL and Javascript SDK

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-fql

I use this function to get photos from a facebook album. Please give advice why it returns blank space.

```
function getPhotos(aid) {
    sql = 'SELECT pid, src_big, src_small FROM photo WHERE aid='+aid+' ORDER BY modified desc';
    FB.api(
        {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: sql
    },
        function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    );  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While posting the error would help, you should wrap the `aid` in quotes since it's a string field ([ref](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo/)):

```
sql = 'SELECT pid, src_big, src_small FROM photo WHERE aid="'+aid+'" ORDER BY modified desc';
```

Also make sure you have the right permission `user_photos`.